# Yii not allowing to insert same data

Tags: php, yii

I'm using yii framework. I have made a condition where users are not allowed to insert a same data.

here is my code

model

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('DEP_CD', 'length', 'max'=>5),
        array('DEP_CD', 'required'),
        array('DEP_CD', 'cekPK'),
    );
}

public function cekPK()
{
    $model = self::findByPk(array($this->DEP_CD));
    if ($model)
        $this->addError('field1', 'Data sudah ada');
}
```

this code works for not allowing user to insert a same data. but when they edit/update the data, it keep saying that data is exist. I need to make users allowed to edit but not inserting the same data only

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work around could be:

```
public function cekPK()
{
    if ($this->isNewRecord)
    {
        $model = self::findByPk(array($this->DEP_CD));
        if ($model)
            $this->addError('field1', 'Data sudah ada');
    }
}
```

Comment: how about if i want to make things like this but with 2 conditions
ex: i want to make new date between '01-08-2017 and 05-08-2017. users can insert one same date as long as not both of them are the same. is that code will works the same? thanks @paul

Comment: I wonder you if your `DBMS` will raise exception, since `DEP_CD` is primary key and it is duplicated. @Trainee